# Magento 2 - Override default product page template file

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I want to add some static data in magento 2 product page in details.phtml

So please tell me how can i override this file without create any new module :

/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just override in your theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

Comment: but i don't have any theme i have to just change in above details.phtml file

Comment: you have to create theme or you have to directly add content inside your module template file

Comment: Using directly override template file is not good practice in magento, You need to override template file using create theme in your magento

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: I created /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml but don't get any changes in front product page

Comment: you have to first read tutorial for craate theme and after that you have to keep this file, link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 0):

add sequence in your module.xml as which module phtml you want ot override like :

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
```

then add file directly with same path as vendor module has and override code.

(if it has in layout you need to override it first then call this default.phtml file through layout xml)